# JQuery not filtering DOM changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a questionnaire page and some `div` have a `data-answered` attribute added to them like this:

```
<div class="question" data-answered="False">
   ... rest of the html
</div>
```

now I have several of those and at some point, through `js` (you can read JQuery) I do:

```
myDiv.data("answered", "True")
```

please assume I have a way to get the actual `div` that's not the issue here. Now I can see that the actual `data-answered` attribute is set to `"True"` when I check the js locals, the DOM explorer however shows nothing. The issue comes however when I need the answered questions count like this:

```
var answeredCount = $('[data-answered=True]').length
```

then no matter how many changes I've made, I always the same elements/results/count as when the page first loaded. However if I do the following:

```
var answeredCount = $('[data-answered]')
      .filter(function () { return $(this).data('answered') == 'True' })
      .length
```

then I get the results I expected. I will be adding an image with some data on an actual browser as prove to I have just said to support my claim:

[image]

**Note:** This behavior seems to occur on Opera and Edge, since I tried it on Chrome and it worked as I expected, haven't tried Firefox.

Is this the intended behavior?
Have I misunderstood something about how JQuery works with the DOM and it changes?
Is it something of only these 2 browsers that makes them special?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle `data-` attributes, you should set it whith the [`.attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method. Like this:

```
myDiv.attr("data-answered", "True")
```

Now, `$('[data-answered=True]')` should work.

That's because [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) stores the data into a internal jQuery place, and doesn't add `data-` attribute to the DOM.

To retrieve data, in the other hand, `.data(key)` both returns data assigned with `.data(key,value)` or the `data-` attributes. From the docs:

> Return the value at the named data store for the first element in the
>   jQuery collection, as set by data(name, value) or by an HTML5 data-*
>   attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Seems every thing goes well.

You could check the document about [jQuery .data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data1)

Briefly, `$(...).data('answered', 'True')` will not change the attr `data-answered="False"` to `data-answered="True"`. `$(...).attr('data-answered', 'True')` does.

Answer (score 0):

With raw javascript, you can achieve desired result, by  below code. 
Probably, you have problems because of comparing by True instead of 'True'

```js
var ans = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("question")).filter(e=> (e.dataset.answered == 'True') ).length


 /*
 *
 * if your browser does not support ES6 syntax
 * Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("question")).filter(function(e){ return e.dataset.answered == 'True' } ).length
 * 
 */

document.getElementById('answered').innerHTML = ans;
```

```html
    <div class="question" data-answered="False">
   ... rest of the html
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="question" data-answered="True">
   ... rest of the html
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="question" data-answered="True">
   ... rest of the html
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="question" data-answered="False">
   ... rest of the html
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="question" data-answered="True">
   ... rest of the html
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="question" data-answered="True">
   ... rest of the html
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="question" data-answered="False">
   ... rest of the html
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div id="results">
      <p>Answered: <span id="answered"></span></p>
    </div>
```